# Unable to pass the "-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true" configuration to the Solr container while using testcontainers library for executing tests

Tags: java, solr, testcontainers

On my system, when I run Solr in the Docker Container, I use this command

```
docker run -p 8983:8983 -v $PWD/:/var/solr/data -v $PWD/configsets:/opt/solr-9.1.1/server/solr/configsets/ -t solr -a "-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true"
```

I am now using testcontainers to deploy Solr Container while executing tests. Now I am unable to figure out how to pass  `"-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true"`   configuration to the container. I have spent couple of hours on this issue but still I am unable to figure it out.

My code is given below, I have tried to use the withCommand function to pass the  `"-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true"` configuration but still I am not getting the expected results.

```
// solrContainer.withCommand("/bin/sh", "-c", "#(nop) ", "CMD [\\\"solr-foreground\\\"]" , "-a", "-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true" );
// solrContainer.withCommand("/bin/solr",  "-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true" );
solrContainer.withCommand("-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true" );
// solrContainer.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(it -> {
//    System.out.println(it.getCmd());
//    System.out.println(it.getEntrypoint());
// });
solrContainer.start();
client = new Http2SolrClient.Builder("http://" + solrContainer.getHost() + ":" + solrContainer.getSolrPort() + "/solr").build();
containerId = solrContainer.getContainerId().substring(0,8);
this.solrConfig = new SolrServerConfig(solrContainer.getHost(), solrContainer.getSolrPort());
try {
  execCmd("docker cp " + solrConfigSetsFolderPath + "/. " + containerId + ":" + "/opt/solr-9.1.1/server/solr/configsets/");
  execCmd("docker cp " + solrConfigSetsFolderPath + " " + containerId + ":" + "/var/solr/data");
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error while copying configsets to Solr ... ");
}
System.out.println("http://" + solrContainer.getHost() + ":" + solrContainer.getSolrPort() + "/solr");
```

Can anyone guide me in this regard? Which function of the testcontainers library can i use for this purpose?

I have also tried to use this function

```
solrContainer.withEnv("SOLR_OPTS", "-Dsolr.disable.allowUrls=true");
```

but then I am getting this error
[image]
Thanks

Comment: What code do you use to run testcontainers? Which language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am working on Java. I have edited my question and added the code. I have tried to use the withCommand() function using various ways but still not getting the expected results.

Comment: dis you try with `.withEnv("solr.disable.allowUrls", "true")`

Comment: it also did not work